# Id of new paper or sites

Tags: android, flutter, backend, superlearner

How to get the source id of any newspaper for my news app
like The Hindu,Times of India etc.
because in my app I have only access to the the other country?
So please help me
so that I can complete my project and share
it with my family.

I just want my answer
and what else can I expect.